# How to Change PushON - PushOFF Power Button to HoldON - HoldOFF

Tags: switches, logic-gates

Using the integrated circuit MC14093B (quad 2-input NAND) you can be able to convert a pushbutton to a latching ON-OFF toggle switch.

This circuit is able to do that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOe6il.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some applications, to prevent accidental powerON / powerOFF use an HoldON / HoldOFF system.

What is needed to change the circuit's behavior to XsecondsHoldON / XsecondsHoldOFF?. Let's say Xseconds = 3-5 seconds.

Comment: Typically when you want to time events lasting more than a few milliseconds, it's easier to use a tiny microcontroller than to make a discrete logic circuit, and that's what most people will probably recommend for this project as well.

Comment: If there are safety issues to be considered I would recommend using proven off the shelf solutions.  Otherwise I 2nd @ThePhoton's proposal of using an embedded processor.  As many more features can be incorporated in the design such as a count down display or an audible pre-start alarm.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to use a micro controller, but I recommend discrete circuits not even logic circuits if possible. Then you are able to prevent electromagnetic interference (EMI). Think of it.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest a tiny uctrl suited for these kind of applications? Its current consumption is very important, because the application is battery powered.

Answer (score 1):

Two resistors connected serial, one end to vcc, another to a capacitor. A switch from grounds to the middle of the two resistors. Pick a large value for the resistor between the switch and the capacitor.

The voltage across the capacitor will only trigger a low if the switch is held sufficiently long.

The output can go to a flip flop or a MCU input pin.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm trying it with Arduino. Can you suggest please some values? What variables change the time?

Answer (score 0):

I found on http://www.mosaic-industries.com:

The following shows a NAND gate latch implementing the desired action:
Circuit schematic of a dual NAND gate latch that turns ON with a button press and OFF with a longer button hold.

When power is first applied, the output is held low for 3 seconds, during which time the button has no effect. After that, a momentary press latches the output high, and a long press of greater than 3 seconds latches the output low again.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIw7Ga.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I know it, thank you. Unfortunately I need also to hold to power ON.